# Asp.Net Version error after deploying to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, localhost

I have developed my Application in asp.net 4.0 and I want to run it on localhost.

So I deployed my project in IIS but after deploying when I went to change Application pool from 2.0 to 4.0 I didn't find version 4.0 in application pool.

So I went to following path to check that Asp.net 4.0 version available or not.
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

But I didn't find version 4.0, Only version 2.0 Available.

I have done following things to run my application on localhost

1. Installed Windows 7
2. Installed IIS (with full features)
3. Deployed successfully my project to IIS

What I am missing here ?

Please help guys....

Comment: Have you installed .Net 4?

Comment: You mean visual studio 10 ?

Comment: Do you never update your machine? [.NET 4 has been in Windows Update for ages](http://superuser.com/questions/298025/does-windows-7-have-net-4-installed-by-default).

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi No, I mean the v4 of the .Net Framework that is not part of a Windows 7 install (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting at installing .NET 4.0.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: :O
But I thought it is not necessary to install Visual Studio to run application on localhost

Comment: @Shaiwal that link does not download Visual Studio. That is the .NET runtime and BCL.

Comment: That is the .NET framework, not Visual Studio. Give it a go.

Comment: If you're going to run a publicly accessible site from this machine, update it first. No need to download the .NET framework yourself.